# Forecasting a time series using yule-walker predicts to small value

Tags: matlab, prediction, forecasting, autoregressive-models

I'm trying to forecast a value at step n+1 using yule-walker ar approach in matlab. The problem is that when plotting my predicted values they seem to small, like the predicted signal being a scaled version of the original.

To put my problem very simple I wrote this stripped down version that inputs a ramp (instead of a signal I measured) to be forecasted.

```
x = [-5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5];
a = aryule(x,9); % uses Yule-Walker modelling
pred = filter(-a(2:end),1,x);
disp(pred(end)); % the predicted value at time n+1
```

The result: `3.4415` While it should be something like 6 ... Any ideas on what I could be missing here?